# Install Oracle Client via Ansible on Windows Machine - exit code 259, 1

Tags: windows, oracle, ansible

I'm trying to install Oracle Client 12c on a Windows Server 2016 via Ansible.

I have tried various options to install the client:

**Option 1**

```
  - name: "Install Oracle Client"
  win_command: "C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\setup.exe -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereq -waitforcompletion -showProgress -silent -responseFile C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\response\\client.rsp"
```

The error code I get is:

```
fatal: [windoze]: FAILED! => {
"changed": true, 
"cmd": "C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\setup.exe -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereq -waitforcompletion -showProgress -silent -responseFile C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\response\\client.rsp", 
"delta": "0:00:10.592896", 
"end": "2018-11-22 12:34:33.774009", 
"msg": "non-zero return code", 
"rc": 1, 
"start": "2018-11-22 12:34:23.181113", 
"stderr": "", 
"stderr_lines": [], 
"stdout": "\r\n Exit code of OUI process 1=", 
"stdout_lines": [
    "", 
    " Exit code of OUI process 1="
]
```

}

**Option 2**

```
- name: "Install Oracle Client"
  win_package:
    path: C:\Temp\Software\Oracle-Client\client\setup.exe
    creates_path: C:\app\client_1
    arguments:
    - "-silent -noconsole -waitforcompletion -responseFile C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\response\\client.rsp"
    state: present
```

The error I get is:

```
fatal: [windoze]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"exit_code": 1, 
"msg": "unexpected rc from install  C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\setup.exe: see rc, stdout and stderr for more details", 
"rc": 1, 
"reboot_required": false, 
"restart_required": false, 
"stderr": "", 
"stderr_lines": [], 
"stdout": "\r\n Exit code of OUI process 1=", 
"stdout_lines": [
    "", 
    " Exit code of OUI process 1="
]
```

}

**Option 3**

```
- name: "Install Oracle Client"
  win_shell: "C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\setup.exe -silent -waitforcompletion -nowelcome -noconfig -debug -force -responseFile C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\response\\client.rsp"
```

The result is different this time where the RC is 1, but it doesn't actually install anything on the server

```
changed: [windoze] => {
"changed": true, 
"cmd": "C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\setup.exe -silent -waitforcompletion -nowelcome -noconfig -debug -force -responseFile C:\\Temp\\Software\\Oracle-Client\\client\\response\\client.rsp", 
"delta": "0:00:09.554881", 
"end": "2018-11-22 12:51:00.633519", 
"rc": 0, 
"start": "2018-11-22 12:50:51.078638", 
"stderr": "", 
"stderr_lines": [], 
"stdout": "\r\n Exit code of OUI process 1=", 
"stdout_lines": [
    "", 
    " Exit code of OUI process 1="
]
```

}

Each of the commands above work manually on the server, so I know that it is not an issue with the commands themselves. It appears that a java process starts when the installer is run which causes this issue when invoked via Ansible. 
Does anyone know how I can successfully install this via Ansible?

Comment: according to [the fine manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/em.920/a96697/oui.htm#445164), the exit code of 1 means the install succeeded, but just failed to do some optional stuff; it also claims to write out some log files, too. Do you know for sure it did not install, and have you found any such log files?

Comment: Yes, the installation doesn't happen. Ansible exits almost immediately. I observed that the OUI process would terminate almost immediately when Ansible is run. I have no issues in running the setup command manually.

Answer (score 4):

You need use -waitforcompletion option, in order to get error 0. This option support only local execute (for example bat). This is working:

In my case is:

```
- name: Execute bat file
  script: files/run.bat
  args:
    creates: C:\app\oracle
```

run.bat

```
C:\OracleClient\client32\setup.exe -silent -nowait -noconsole -waitforcompletion -responseFile "C:\OracleClient\client.rsp"
```

[Here more information](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/OUIRF/silent.htm#OUIRF354)

Comment: Thank you, `-waitforcompletion` is the essential argument, although at least with Oracle 19c this works for me even *without* a wrapper script. See also my [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61867292/1811525).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue while installing Oracle Databse 12c R2 engine (12.2.0.1.0).
Wraping the command up into a batch file resolved my problem. Here is my install.bat.j2 jinja template's content:

```
setup.exe -silent "ORACLE_HOME={{ oracle_home }}" "ORACLE_BASE={{ oracle_base }}" -showProgress -noconfig -waitforcompletion -responseFile "{{ ansible_env.TEMP }}\oracle_winx64_12201_database\db_install.rsp"
```

Usage in Ansible playbook:

```
   - name: Install Oracle Database 12c Release 2 engine
     win_command: "install.bat"
     args:
       chdir: "{{ ansible_env.TEMP }}\\installation_package"
```

I also noticed a following line describing **-waitforcompletion** parameter in the official Oracle's [document](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/OUIRF/silent.htm#OUIRF334):

> NOTE: this option only works if the command is invoked from a script; for example, if a .bat file contains the setup.exe file with the -waitforcompletion option. This option will not work if invoked directly from the command line prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue installing the 12c client on Red Hat.
As Matthew has described, the installation completes, but the exit code is 1 due to a prerequisite failure. In my case, it was an optional dependency.
I don't particularly like this solution, but if the installation is definitely successful, you can try adding the following argument to the command:

`-ignoreSysPrereqs` For ignoring the results of the system prerequisite checks.

Comment: But the same install command works fine when executed manually on the server. It just doesn't work when executed via Ansible.

Comment: It does look as though it was successful on Linux as well, however when I run `echo $?`, the exit code is 1.
You can check the same with `echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%` on Windows afaik.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that installing an Oracle 19c Client on a Windows Server works without a separate batch script (not tested with earlier versions):

```
  - name: Install Oracle 19c Client
    win_command: setup.exe -silent -nowait -waitforcompletion -responseFile C:\Provisioning\Oracle\client.rsp
    args:
      chdir: C:\Provisioning\Oracle\client\
```

During my first attempt I omitted the argument `-waitforcompletion` which resulted in the exit code `259`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned under Option 1, "Exit code of OUI process 1=" can typically be expanded on by reviewing the "installActions.log" file found under "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs". In fact, that's the best goto logfile for troubleshooting anything related to setup.exe/OUI (Oracle Universal Installer).

ps. In my case, it was a typo in the filename of the response file.