# Install Oracle Client from command line without user-interaction

Tags: windows, oracle, command-line, installation, build-automation

I am looking for a way to install Oracle client on Windows but running from command line. In order to run it automatically there shall be **no user-interaction**.

The Oracle documentation is quite sparse for command line options of Oracle Universal Installer. Even when running the setup as `setup.exe -silent -responseFile filename.rsp` the user has to press ENTER at certain point.

Comment: Why don't you use the instant client? The "installation" is as simple as extracting a zip archive.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, if you need tools like SQLplus or ODBC driver or ODP.NET provider or tnsping, etc. then the instant client is not sufficient.

Comment: There are additional packages for SQLPlus and ODBC, but you are right, it does not work for .Net

Comment: Yes, SQLPlus and ODBC might be poor examples but there are many components you may need which are not provided by additional packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Oracle Client via Ansible on Windows Machine - exit code 259, 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431566/install-oracle-client-via-ansible-on-windows-machine-exit-code-259-1)

Comment: @030 No it does not. Question is not about how to call `setup.exe`, its about the parameters. Apart from that, here is an accepted answer for 2 years now. And when you have a look at the number of upvotes, then it seems to be the much better answer anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some investigations I found out how to get the full command line options:

```
setup.exe -help
```

This works for version 11.2, 12.1 and 12.2. In version 18c and 19c this does work not anymore, instead you have to execute:

```
setup.exe -help -silent
```

Here the example output of an 18c setup:

```
Usage:  setup.exe [<flag>] [<option>]
Following are the possible flags:
    -help - display help.
    -silent - run in silent mode. The inputs can be a response file or a list of command line variable value pairs.
            [-ignorePrereqFailure - ignore all prerequisite checks failures.]
            [-lenientInstallMode - perform the best effort installation by automatically ignoring invalid data in input parameters.]
            [-showProgress - show the installation progress on the console. This option is supported for silent mode installation only.]
    -responseFile - specify the complete path of the response file to use.
    -invPtrLoc - point to a different inventory location. The orainst.loc file contains the location of the central inventory (inventory_loc) and the inventory group (inst_group).
    -jreLoc - specify the location for the jre used in the installation.
    -logLevel - enable the log of messages up to the priority level provided in this argument. Valid options are: severe, warning, info, config, fine, finer, finest.
    -paramFile - specify the location of the oraparam.ini file to be used in the installation.
    -executePrereqs | -executeConfigTools | -deinstall
    -executePrereqs - execute the prerequisite checks only.
    -executeConfigTools - execute the config tools for an installed home.
            [-all - execute all the config tools for an installed home, including the config tools that have already succeeded.]
    -deinstall - uninstall the specified home.
    -debug - run in debug mode.
    -executeSysPrereqs - execute the system prerequisite checks and exit.
    -ignoreSysPrereqs - ignore the results of the system prerequisite checks.
    -printdiskusage - log the debug information for the disk usage.
    -printmemory - log the debug information for the memory usage.
    -printtime - log the debug information for the time usage.
    -waitForCompletion - wait for the completion of the installation, instead of spawning the installer and returning the console prompt.
    -suppressPreCopyScript - suppress the execution of the precopy script.
    -acceptUntrustedCertificates - accept untrusted certificates from a secure site.
    -suppressPostCopyScript - suppress the execution of the postcopy script.
    -noconfig - do not execute the config tools.
    -noconsole - suppress the display of messages in the console. The console is not allocated.
    -ignoreInternalDriverError - ignore any internal driver errors.
    -promptForPassword - provide the passwords on the console during a silent installation of an Oracle database.
    -remotecp - specify the path to the remote copy program on the local cluster node. Used only for cluster installs.
    -remoteshell - specify the path to the remote shell program on the local cluster node. Used only for cluster installs.
```

Finally I managed to run full setup with single command even without a Response file which can be executed by a software deployment system. Here are some examples (needs to be in a single line):

```
setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereq -waitforcompletion -force \
   "INVENTORY_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory" \
   "ORACLE_BASE=c:\oracle\product" \
   "ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64" \
   "SELECTED_LANGUAGES=de,en,fr,it" \
   "oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=true" \
   "oracle.install.client.installType=Custom" \
   "oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:12.1.0.2.0,oracle.sqlplus:12.1.0.2.0,oracle.odbc:12.1.0.2.0"


setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereqFailure -skipPrereqs -waitForCompletion -force \
   "INVENTORY_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory" \
   "ORACLE_BASE=c:\oracle\product" \
   "ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x64" \
   "oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=true" \
   "oracle.install.client.installType=Custom" \
   "oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:12.2.0.1.0,oracle.sqlplus:12.2.0.1.0,oracle.odbc:12.2.0.1.0"


setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereqFailure -waitForCompletion -force \
   "ORACLE_BASE=c:\oracle\product" \
   "ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\18c\Client_x86" \
   "oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=true" \
   "oracle.install.client.installType=Custom" \
   "oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:18.0.0.0.0,oracle.sqlplus:18.0.0.0.0,oracle.odbc:18.0.0.0.0"
```

Note, option `-nowait` is not mentioned in help but required to suppress prompt "Press ENTER to close the program".

Option `-force` is not mentioned in help of version 12.2 and newer but seems to be still valid to force installation in non-empty directory

Apparently 18c 32-bit installer does not like option `"INVENTORY_LOCATION=C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory"`, skip this entry. Using `"INVENTORY_LOCATION=C:\PROGRA~2\Oracle\Inventory"` causes an exception for lock files in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\locks\`

### Update

I am working on an update of our clients. Even with old installer I did not manage it to run the setup properly. I always have to use the response file, e.g.

```
setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereqFailure -waitForCompletion -force -responseFile ../client_x86_21c.rsp
```

Specifying the components in the command line does not work (anymore).

I was not able to run the **32-bit** Oracle Universal Installer 18c - seems to be a bug. Since this version is EOL meanwhile, I did not further investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereq -waitForCompletion \
-force "INVENTORY_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory" \
"ORACLE_BASE=c:\oracle\product" "ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x64" \
"oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=true" \
"oracle.install.client.installType=Administrator" \
"oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:12.2.0.1.0,oracle.sqlplus:12.2.0.1.0,oracle.odbc:12.2.0.1.0"
```

This works for me. This will install Oracle Client Admin version from Command Prompt in Windows 10 {as i have used}. Thanks to the earlier posts.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think when you install "Administrator" version, then you cannot specify any custom components (they might be ignored)

Comment: how can i keep cursor in same line till the installation completes. In my case, after given the statement in Command Prompt, I need to press enter. Then it starts to install and cursor moves to next line. Offcourse Setup is running. But how to control the cursor rather moving to next line?

Comment: Do you really care about the cursor position? I don't think you can control that.

Comment: I am trying to "Installing Oracle Client in Windows Container" which is not happening. I thought the issue with Command Position. As soon as the cursor coming to new position, Setup.exe running for a minute and stoping.

Comment: Maybe try option `-force`

Comment: Tried below: still no luck.   setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereq -waitForCompletion \
-force "INVENTORY_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory" \
"ORACLE_BASE=c:\oracle\product" "ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x64" \
"oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=true" \
"oracle.install.client.installType=Administrator" \
"oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:12.2.0.1.0,oracle.sqlplus:12.2.0.1.0,oracle.odbc:12.2.0.1.0"