# Installation issue with Oracle12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm having issues installing Oracle 12c on my desktop, which is a Win8.1. Previously, I had Oracle 12c installed on this computer and was also able to install it today on my work computer, which is a Win10 laptop.

The installation goes past the CMD window but then it gets stuck on the menu. As you can see the menu is blank.

[image]

These are the last lines from the log file that must be creating the issue:

```
INFO: Validating state <supportedOSCheck>

INFO: Verifying target environment...

INFO: Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined...
```

The installation gets stuck in the "Checking whether the IP address of the localhost could be determined..." part.

Could it be a blocked port? Has someone else experienced this issue?

Regards.

Edit: The only fix for this issue at the moment was to install a virtual machine and install oracle DB there.

Comment: Contact Oracle support, These questions are not really ontopic here..

Comment: You may try the installation with `-ignoreSysPrereqs` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction

Comment: Already posted in their forums but no one has replied.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix the issue with the following steps;

1. Make sure all Oracle related services are stopped. You can ensure that by checking your service manager.
2. You may now proceed to delete the folder by name `CVU_12.2.0.1.0_[your_account_name]` at

```
C:\Users\[your_account_name]\AppData\Local\Temp\CVU_12.2.0.1.0_[your_account_name]
```

3. Open a CMD as admin and go to the folder where `setup.exe` for Oracle12c is located, paste the code in the snippet below and run it.

```
setup.exe -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I faced this issue. It's important that there are 2 commands to skip system check. One is for Oracle client installation and another one is for Oracle db installation. If you are facing issue with Oracle client, you can use

```
setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"
```

Command mentioned in the previous post is also correct but valid for Oracle db installation

Answer (score 0):

For a version 19 client installation, I followed the first and second suggestions, and made some headway with the installer, as it was not getting stuck any longer.  But due to the deletion of the CVU folder, an OracleRemExedServiceV2 service got marked for deletion, and the console command for the client installer was ending with an error. So I ran the installer again, without the command-line parameters, and the installer ran true to completion.  Hurray, and thanks to Kamal, Lingote and Nyedidikeke!