# How to install oracle 11g in ubuntu 18.04 server without desktop interface?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, silent-installer

I want to install and configure a oracle 11g server in ubuntu 18.04 OS without desktop interfice. I have the ubuntu server in VirtualBox with 2 netwotk interfices NAT and VirtualBox Host-Only. I want to install this oracle without desktop interfice to run the OS machines with bad hardware.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction/61563237#61563237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do **Silent Installation** using a `response file` to provide all the required information for the installation, so no additional user input is required. The response file called `db_install.rsp` in the response directory. You can manually edit this file and use it for a silent installation.

```
./runInstaller -silent -responseFile <response_file_dir>
```

Following is an example of the response file in `11gR2`:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Do not change the following system generated value. 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.responseFileVersion=/oracle/install/rspfmt_dbinstall_response_schema_v11_2_0

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the installation option.
# It can be one of the following:
#   - INSTALL_DB_SWONLY
#   - INSTALL_DB_AND_CONFIG
#   - UPGRADE_DB
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.option=INSTALL_DB_SWONLY

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the hostname of the system as set during the install. It can be used
# to force the installation to use an alternative hostname rather than using the
# first hostname found on the system. (e.g., for systems with multiple hostnames 
# and network interfaces)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ol7-112.localdomain

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Unix group to be set for the inventory directory.  
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNIX_GROUP_NAME=oinstall

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the location which holds the inventory files.
# This is an optional parameter if installing on
# Windows based Operating System.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INVENTORY_LOCATION=/u01/app/oraInventory
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the languages in which the components will be installed.             
# 
# en   : English                  ja   : Japanese                  
# fr   : French                   ko   : Korean                    
# ar   : Arabic                   es   : Latin American Spanish    
# bn   : Bengali                  lv   : Latvian                   
# pt_BR: Brazilian Portuguese     lt   : Lithuanian                
# bg   : Bulgarian                ms   : Malay                     
# fr_CA: Canadian French          es_MX: Mexican Spanish           
# ca   : Catalan                  no   : Norwegian                 
# hr   : Croatian                 pl   : Polish                    
# cs   : Czech                    pt   : Portuguese                
# da   : Danish                   ro   : Romanian                  
# nl   : Dutch                    ru   : Russian                   
# ar_EG: Egyptian                 zh_CN: Simplified Chinese        
# en_GB: English (Great Britain)  sk   : Slovak                    
# et   : Estonian                 sl   : Slovenian                 
# fi   : Finnish                  es_ES: Spanish                   
# de   : German                   sv   : Swedish                   
# el   : Greek                    th   : Thai                      
# iw   : Hebrew                   zh_TW: Traditional Chinese       
# hu   : Hungarian                tr   : Turkish                   
# is   : Icelandic                uk   : Ukrainian                 
# in   : Indonesian               vi   : Vietnamese                
# it   : Italian                                                   
#
# all_langs   : All languages
#
# Specify value as the following to select any of the languages.
# Example : SELECTED_LANGUAGES=en,fr,ja
#
# Specify value as the following to select all the languages.
# Example : SELECTED_LANGUAGES=all_langs  
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECTED_LANGUAGES=en,en_GB

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the complete path of the Oracle Home. 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the complete path of the Oracle Base. 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the installation edition of the component.                     
#                                                             
# The value should contain only one of these choices.        
#   - EE     : Enterprise Edition                                
#   - SE     : Standard Edition                                  
#   - SEONE  : Standard Edition One
#   - PE     : Personal Edition (WINDOWS ONLY)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.InstallEdition=EE

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable is used to enable or disable custom install and is considered
# only if InstallEdition is EE.
#
#   - true  : Components mentioned as part of 'optionalComponents' property
#             are considered for install.
#   - false : Value for 'optionalComponents' is not considered.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.EEOptionsSelection=false

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This property is considered only if 'EEOptionsSelection' is set to true 
#
# Description: List of Enterprise Edition Options you would like to enable.
#
#              The following choices are available. You may specify any
#              combination of these choices.  The components you choose should
#              be specified in the form "internal-component-name:version"
#              Below is a list of components you may specify to enable.
#        
#              oracle.oraolap:11.2.0.4.0 - Oracle OLAP
#              oracle.rdbms.dm:11.2.0.4.0 - Oracle Data Mining RDBMS Files
#              oracle.rdbms.dv:11.2.0.4.0- Oracle Database Vault option
#              oracle.rdbms.lbac:11.2.0.4.0 - Oracle Label Security
#              oracle.rdbms.partitioning:11.2.0.4.0 - Oracle Partitioning
#              oracle.rdbms.rat:11.2.0.4.0 - Oracle Real Application Testing
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.optionalComponents=

###############################################################################
#                                                                             #
# PRIVILEGED OPERATING SYSTEM GROUPS                                          #
# ------------------------------------------                                  #
# Provide values for the OS groups to which OSDBA and OSOPER privileges       #
# needs to be granted. If the install is being performed as a member of the   #
# group "dba", then that will be used unless specified otherwise below.       #
#                                                                             #
# The value to be specified for OSDBA and OSOPER group is only for UNIX based #
# Operating System.                                                           #
#                                                                             #
###############################################################################

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The DBA_GROUP is the OS group which is to be granted OSDBA privileges.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.DBA_GROUP=dba

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The OPER_GROUP is the OS group which is to be granted OSOPER privileges.
# The value to be specified for OSOPER group is optional.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.OPER_GROUP=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the cluster node names selected during the installation.                                      
# Example : oracle.install.db.CLUSTER_NODES=node1,node2
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.CLUSTER_NODES=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable is used to enable or disable RAC One Node install.
#
#   - true  : Value of RAC One Node service name is used.
#   - false : Value of RAC One Node service name is not used.
#
# If left blank, it will be assumed to be false.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.isRACOneInstall=false

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the name for RAC One Node Service. 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.racOneServiceName=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the type of database to create.
# It can be one of the following:
#   - GENERAL_PURPOSE/TRANSACTION_PROCESSING                       
#   - DATA_WAREHOUSE                                
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.type=GENERAL_PURPOSE

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Starter Database Global Database Name. 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.globalDBName=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Starter Database SID.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.SID=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Starter Database character set.
#                                               
#  One of the following
#  AL32UTF8, WE8ISO8859P15, WE8MSWIN1252, EE8ISO8859P2,
#  EE8MSWIN1250, NE8ISO8859P10, NEE8ISO8859P4, BLT8MSWIN1257,
#  BLT8ISO8859P13, CL8ISO8859P5, CL8MSWIN1251, AR8ISO8859P6,
#  AR8MSWIN1256, EL8ISO8859P7, EL8MSWIN1253, IW8ISO8859P8,
#  IW8MSWIN1255, JA16EUC, JA16EUCTILDE, JA16SJIS, JA16SJISTILDE,
#  KO16MSWIN949, ZHS16GBK, TH8TISASCII, ZHT32EUC, ZHT16MSWIN950,
#  ZHT16HKSCS, WE8ISO8859P9, TR8MSWIN1254, VN8MSWIN1258
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.characterSet=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable should be set to true if Automatic Memory Management 
# in Database is desired.
# If Automatic Memory Management is not desired, and memory allocation
# is to be done manually, then set it to false.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.memoryOption=false

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the total memory allocation for the database. Value(in MB) should be
# at least 256 MB, and should not exceed the total physical memory available 
# on the system.
# Example: oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.memoryLimit=512
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.memoryLimit=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable controls whether to load Example Schemas onto
# the starter database or not.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.installExampleSchemas=false

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable includes enabling audit settings, configuring password profiles
# and revoking some grants to public. These settings are provided by default. 
# These settings may also be disabled.     
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.enableSecuritySettings=true

###############################################################################
#                                                                             #
# Passwords can be supplied for the following four schemas in the         #
# starter database:                                   #
#   SYS                                                                       #
#   SYSTEM                                                                    #
#   SYSMAN (used by Enterprise Manager)                                       #
#   DBSNMP (used by Enterprise Manager)                                       #
#                                                                             #
# Same password can be used for all accounts (not recommended)            #
# or different passwords for each account can be provided (recommended)       #
#                                                                             #
###############################################################################

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable holds the password that is to be used for all schemas in the
# starter database.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.password.ALL=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the SYS password for the starter database.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.password.SYS=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the SYSTEM password for the starter database.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.password.SYSTEM=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the SYSMAN password for the starter database.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.password.SYSMAN=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the DBSNMP password for the starter database.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.password.DBSNMP=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the management option to be selected for the starter database. 
# It can be one of the following:
#   - GRID_CONTROL
#   - DB_CONTROL
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.control=DB_CONTROL

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Management Service to use if Grid Control is selected to manage 
# the database.      
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.gridcontrol.gridControlServiceURL=

###############################################################################
#                                                                             #
# SPECIFY BACKUP AND RECOVERY OPTIONS                                         #
# ------------------------------------                                    #
# Out-of-box backup and recovery options for the database can be mentioned    #
# using the entries below.                            # 
#                                                                             #
###############################################################################

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This variable is to be set to false if automated backup is not required. Else 
# this can be set to true.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.automatedBackup.enable=false

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Regardless of the type of storage that is chosen for backup and recovery, if 
# automated backups are enabled, a job will be scheduled to run daily to backup 
# the database. This job will run as the operating system user that is 
# specified in this variable.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.automatedBackup.osuid=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Regardless of the type of storage that is chosen for backup and recovery, if 
# automated backups are enabled, a job will be scheduled to run daily to backup 
# the database. This job will run as the operating system user specified by the 
# above entry. The following entry stores the password for the above operating 
# system user.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.automatedBackup.ospwd=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the type of storage to use for the database.
# It can be one of the following:
#   - FILE_SYSTEM_STORAGE
#   - ASM_STORAGE
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.storageType=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the database file location which is a directory for datafiles, control
# files, redo logs.         
#
# Applicable only when oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.storage=FILE_SYSTEM_STORAGE 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.fileSystemStorage.dataLocation=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the backup and recovery location.
#
# Applicable only when oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.storage=FILE_SYSTEM_STORAGE 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.fileSystemStorage.recoveryLocation=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the existing ASM disk groups to be used for storage.
#
# Applicable only when oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.storageType=ASM_STORAGE
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.asm.diskGroup=

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the password for ASMSNMP user of the ASM instance.                 
#
# Applicable only when oracle.install.db.config.starterdb.storage=ASM_STORAGE 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.db.config.asm.ASMSNMPPassword=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the My Oracle Support Account Username.
#
#  Example   : MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=abc@oracle.com
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the My Oracle Support Account Username password.
#
# Example    : MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=password
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify whether to enable the user to set the password for
# My Oracle Support credentials. The value can be either true or false.
# If left blank it will be assumed to be false.
#
# Example    : SECURITY_UPDATES_VIA_MYORACLESUPPORT=true
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SECURITY_UPDATES_VIA_MYORACLESUPPORT=false

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify whether user doesn't want to configure Security Updates.
# The value for this variable should be true if you don't want to configure
# Security Updates, false otherwise.
#
# The value can be either true or false. If left blank it will be assumed
# to be false.
#
# Example    : DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=false
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=true

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Proxy server name. Length should be greater than zero.
#
# Example    : PROXY_HOST=proxy.domain.com 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROXY_HOST=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the proxy port number. Should be Numeric and at least 2 chars.
#
# Example    : PROXY_PORT=25
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROXY_PORT=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the proxy user name. Leave PROXY_USER and PROXY_PWD
# blank if your proxy server requires no authentication.
#
# Example    : PROXY_USER=username
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROXY_USER=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the proxy password. Leave PROXY_USER and PROXY_PWD  
# blank if your proxy server requires no authentication.
#
# Example    : PROXY_PWD=password
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROXY_PWD=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the proxy realm. 
#
# Example    : PROXY_REALM=metalink
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROXY_REALM=
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Oracle Support Hub URL. 
# 
# Example    : COLLECTOR_SUPPORTHUB_URL=https://orasupporthub.company.com:8080/
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COLLECTOR_SUPPORTHUB_URL=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the auto-updates option. It can be one of the following:
#   - MYORACLESUPPORT_DOWNLOAD
#   - OFFLINE_UPDATES
#   - SKIP_UPDATES
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.installer.autoupdates.option=SKIP_UPDATES
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# In case MYORACLESUPPORT_DOWNLOAD option is chosen, specify the location where
# the updates are to be downloaded.
# In case OFFLINE_UPDATES option is chosen, specify the location where the updates 
# are present.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.installer.autoupdates.downloadUpdatesLoc=
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the My Oracle Support Account Username which has the patches download privileges  
# to be used for software updates.
#  Example   : AUTOUPDATES_MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=abc@oracle.com
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AUTOUPDATES_MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the My Oracle Support Account Username password which has the patches download privileges  
# to be used for software updates.
#
# Example    : AUTOUPDATES_MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=password
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AUTOUPDATES_MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that while it is technically possible to install on Ubuntu, that this operating system is not certified or supported by Oracle, so no results are guaranteed. If you need a *supported* configuration, check this list for possibilities: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCHGDIE