# Installing ORACLE 11 G on WINDOWS 10 machine

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was wondering if someone could suggest anything here.

I am trying to install Oracle 11g  on my Windows 10 64 bit machine. On my side I am required to install the 64Bit driver first and for whatever reason it stucks at steps 5 of 7.

Checking forum and SO, I saw a suggestion to add the below bit of xml to the cvu_prereq.xml file present in the stage/cvu folder. Yet this has not helped.

```
<OPERATING_SYSTEM RELEASE="6.2">
             <VERSION VALUE="3"/>
             <ARCHITECTURE VALUE="64-bit"/>
             <NAME VALUE="Windows 10"/>
             <ENV_VAR_LIST>
                 <ENV_VAR NAME="PATH" MAX_LENGTH="1023" />
             </ENV_VAR_LIST>
         </OPERATING_SYSTEM>
```

When checking the logs, It seems to stuck each time on 'Get view named [SummaryUI]'.
From the logs it seems my machine fits all the prerequisite.

```
INFO: All forked task are completed at state checkPrereqs
INFO: Completed background operations
INFO: Moved to state <checkPrereqs>
INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations
INFO: Completed background operations
INFO: Validating view at state <checkPrereqs>
INFO: Completed validating view at state <checkPrereqs>
INFO: Validating state <checkPrereqs>
INFO: Using default Validator configured in the Action class oracle.install.ivw.client.action.PrereqAction
INFO: Completed validating state <checkPrereqs>
INFO: Verifying route success
INFO: Get view named [SummaryUI]
```

Has anyone any suggestion for this please? I am at a loss as to why it fails on this very step.

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction

Comment: Thank you Wernfried. This is helpful. I wonder I need to install the 11.g version but the suggestion points to version 12 if I am not wrong. Also I need to install the RUNTIME version. Not sure on how to set this up from command line?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing the following:
As per the suggestion of Wernfried I run the CMD line and run the following:
setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereq -waitForCompletion"ORACLE_BASE=C:\Oracle ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1 
oracle.install.client.installType=Runtime \

This worked for me. I am now able to install 11g Oracle driver on WIN10.
Thanks for the input.