# Oracle Client: Installation with Response Files

Tags: oracle, installation, oracleclient

(Based on a German software version)

I tried to understand the "response files " to install the Oracle Client in a silent mode. I looked at the Online-help, but this didn't answer my questions.

What I want to do?

- Install the "runtime" with some personal settings
- then install one additional function ("custom" installation)

This standard procedure creates two RSP files by itself. Using the "Save response file .." button creates (every time) also a RSP-file, but 10 times smaller than the original files.

My question:

- which files are to use? The automatically or the manually saved ones?
- Can I merge these files to install "runtime + additonal stuff" in only one call?

Regards

(or is is possible to copy&paste from one PC to another - without installation?)

Comment: I don't know what the 'personal settings' or 'additional function' are, but in case it's new to you, consider using Oracle Instant Client which has a simple ZIP install. https://www.oracle.com/au/database/technologies/instant-client.html

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks, but if the response-file is working I will continue to use them at the moment. So I'm sure(?) that it will do the same installation as before.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install only once with "custom", the "runtime" is always included anyway.

Have a look at the response file, most of the lines are comments (starting with `#`) or empty values (e.g. `UNIX_GROUP_NAME=`)

If you take only the relevant lines, then the file will become quite small.

Maybe have a look at [Install Oracle Client from command line without user-interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction)

Yes, you can use the response file on different machines, we used one single file to install Oracle client on more than 1000 PC's

Some notes:

- In 12.1 and later ODP.NET is not added to GAC anymore, see https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2272241_1.html
- Component "Oracle Net" should be always included, see https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1589205.1

Comment: Thanks, Wernfried, I will try and report. BTW: Copying the entire, installed oracle-folder from one PC to another is not OK?

Comment: Should be no problem. But have a quick look into it whether it contains any personal or machine specific settings.

Comment: So the "installation" of the client creates an "encapsuled folder" which contains everything - no registry entries, no DL-usage, no ... ?

Comment: No, this was a misunderstanding, you can only reuse the Response file. The installer modifies the `PATH`, register DLL's, create services and users, changes the registry, etc. - depending on the options you selected. It would be a challenge to run it manually. See [How to uninstall / completely remove Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) to get an idea what the installer does.

Comment: Great! Sali ...

Comment: I checked a rsp-file: 6 kb; 121 lines. Without lines with # keeps 7 lines `oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:12.2.0.1.0
oracle.install.client.installType=Custom
oracle.install.client.schedulerAgentHostName=
oracle.install.client.schedulerAgentPortNumber=
oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=true
oracle.install.OracleHomeUserName=
oracle.install.OracleHomeUserPassword=
oracle.install.responseFileVersion=/oracle/install/rspfmt_clientinstall_response_schema_v12.2.0
ORACLE_BASE=C:\Oracle
ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1
UNIX_GROUP_NAME=`  Is it OK?

Comment: Yes, should be OK