# Oracle 19c Client Silent Install Custom

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am wanting to install Oracle 19c silent with custom install. How do I find the component names to add to the script? We want everything except for 'Oracle Net listener' and 'Oracle Scheduler Agent.' We are installing this across the board on about 100 machines and I would like to have it run.

```
setup.exe -silent -nowait -ignoreSysPrereqs -ignorePrereqFailure -waitForCompletion -force \
   "ORACLE_BASE=c:\oracle\product" \
   "ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\18c\Client_x86" \
   "oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=true" \
   "oracle.install.client.installType=Custom" \
   "oracle.install.client.customComponents=oracle.rdbms.util:18.0.0.0.0,oracle.sqlplus:18.0.0.0.0,oracle.odbc:18.0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: Check also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction

Comment: In case you install ODP.NET, see https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2272241_1.html and check this bug: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1589205.1

Answer (score 0):

Use a Response File to do this. Essentially you run an interactive install once and record the responses, then use the output file as input to the silent install.

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntcli/installing-and-configuring-oracle-database-client-using-response-files.html#GUID-A776B1AF-AF0B-49F6-91CD-DE9CB7B9E7A7