# Oracle Client 19c silent installation Windows: [FATAL] java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, oracleclient

I want to install the 32 bit Oracle Client for the 19c Database on Windows in silent mode.
When I install it in the GUI it works perfectly fine, but when I install it in silent mode i get the error: [FATAL] java.lang.NullPointerException
That is everything I get

That is the Response file I'm using

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Do not change the following system generated value. 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.responseFileVersion=/oracle/install/rspfmt_clientinstall_response_schema_v19.0.0

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Unix group to be set for the inventory directory.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
UNIX_GROUP_NAME=
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Complete path of the Oracle Base.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORACLE_BASE=C:\Oracle
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Specify the Oracle Home user.                 
#
# Use Built-in Account or specify a Windows User Account with limited privilege to 
# install and configure the Oracle Home.
#
# Set oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount to true if you want to use BuiltIn Account.
#
# Set oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount to false if you want to use Windows Account
# user as Oracle Home user. 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.install.IsBuiltInAccount=false
oracle.install.OracleHomeUserName=Oracle
oracle.install.OracleHomeUserPassword=
```

and that is the cmd command I execute

```
c:\Oracle\NT_193000_client_home\setup.exe -silent -waitforcompletion -responseFile "c:\Oracle\NT_193000_client_home\install\response\client.rsp" ORACLE_BASE="c:\Oracle" oracle.install.OracleHomeUserPassword="password"
```

I also tried to:

- Leave out the "
- Leave out the ORACLE_BASE and oracle.install.OracleHomeUserPassword of the command and put both in the response file
- Add -force, -noconsole and -nowait to the command

The responseFile is generated by Oracle and is the same as the template response file. The only difference is that I've added the values.

Executing the same command and leave out the -silent works perfectly. The GUI opens, everything is filled out right and i just have to hit enter 4 times to install it.

I've searched for multible hours but wasn't able to find something.
Help would be much appriciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction there are a few more options you can try.

Comment: I've tried some of these options that would make sense but that did'nt fix the problem either. The -ignoreSysPrereqs and -ignorePrereq were no known commands

Comment: Do you see anything in the logfile?

Comment: Nope theres nothing in the logfile. I can only see stuff for the Database installation in the logfile but not for the client for some reason. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong logfile.
I also tried to add -debug to the command but that couldn't help me either

Comment: Are you sure you actually need the "full" Client?  Can you use Instant Client instead? This is a simple zip install. The Windows 32-bit packages are at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. So yeah I need the full Client

Answer (score 0):

When I developed the installation package (version 12.1) I faced several issues:

- Setup must run with an Administrator account
- ORACLE_BASE must exist

I set this environment variable:

```
SET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en
```

Remove these Registry key:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE`
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` (for 64-bit Client)

Delete these files/folders:

- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\Inventory\oui`
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML`
- `%ProgramFiles%\Oracle\Inventory\oui` (for 64-bit Client)
- `%ProgramFiles%\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML` (for 64-bit Client)
- `%TEMP%\deinstall*`
- `%TEMP%\OraInstall*`
- `%TEMP%\CVU*`

Maybe comment `oracle.install.OracleHomeUserPassword` in response file if you specify it as command line parameter. Remove the quotes `"`, folder name must not contain any space characters anyway. Put the `setup.exe` to a different folder than the installation folder.

Comment: Alright I tried all of it now and still I get the java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Then I would suggest to open a case at Oracle.