# Ansible - Install Client Oracle stops

Tags: linux, oracle, ansible, redhat, ansible-tower

Hy,

When I run this command on my target server it works perfectly :

```
/home/logiciel/oracle/v19c/client/runInstaller -showProgress -silent -responseFile /home/logiciel/oracle/v19c/client/response/client_install.rsp
```

During the installation, it displays  "   Veuillez patientez...[ora@myserver1]  " ensuite il continue l'installation.

On the other hand, on Ansible Tower when I run this same command with the module, it stops at
"   Veuillez patientez...  " and he considers the task successful.

```
- name: Install Oracle Client
  command: "/home/logiciel/oracle/v19c/client/runInstaller -showProgress -silent -responseFile /home/logiciel/oracle/v19c/client/response/client_install.rsp"
  register: client_runinstaller_output
  become: yes
  become_user: ora19
  failed_when: "'Successfully Setup Software' not in client_runinstaller_output.stdout"
```

I think Ansible Tower sees the prompt in the middle of the installation and it thinks the task is done...

Could you help me please ?
Thank you very much

```
- name: Install Oracle Client
  command: "/home/logiciel/oracle/v19c/client/runInstaller -showProgress -silent -responseFile /home/logiciel/oracle/v19c/client/response/client_install.rsp"
  register: client_runinstaller_output
  become: yes
  become_user: ora19
  failed_when: "'Successfully Setup Software' not in client_runinstaller_output.stdout"
```

I think Ansible Tower sees the prompt in the middle of the installation and it thinks the task is done...

Comment: This one may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792726/install-oracle-client-from-command-line-without-user-interaction